# Bluemix SSO Configuration

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I have some challenges configuring Bluemix SSO Service with a Spring application that is bundled as a jar file.

I need to understand:

1. If Bluemix SSO configuration is supported for a app.jar file (instead of a war). I do not want to change ths for now
2. Is Bluemix SSO supported in Tomcat application in Bluemix.

I was able to successfully test SSO with a war file, but it breaks for a jar file.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

The Bluemix Single Sign On Service, supports Node.JS and JAVA(Liberty) Applications.

If the .jar is created via JAVA(Liberty) and has a Server.xml file so it can read the oidc configuration, it should be able to work.

If there is no Server.xml file then the SSO Binding will fail.